# Можно ли переопределить объект внутри конструктора?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Задача в следующем: Есть 2 класса один наследуется от другого и есть класс который вызывается в скрипте. Требуется вызвать методы нужного класса при определенных условиях, не меняя вызов класса в скрипте. Возможно ли так сделать?

Пример кода

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = '1'
        self.testt = '2'

    def open(self):
        print('open A')


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.testt = '3'

    def open(self):
        print('open B')


class BA(): 
     def __init__(self):
        if 4 == 3:
            ??????? - вызвать методы A
        else:
            ?????? - вызвать методы B



BC().open()
```

Comment: Что значит "вызвать В".Это же класс, а не функция?

Comment: Вызвать метод этого класса

Comment: `B( ).open()` ?

Comment: не, мне интересно можно ли классом BA переопределять методы в зависимости от условия, своего рода посредник между A и B

Comment: if 4 == 3: ? Вы серьёзно ?

Comment: для примера же написал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что вы хотите, то лучше переопределить метод `__new__`, чтобы в зависимости от условия создавался либо экземпляр A, либо экземпляр B.

```
class BA(): 
    def __new__(cls):
        if 4 == 3:
            obj = super().__new__(A)
        else:
            obj = super().__new__(B)
        obj.__init__()
        return obj
```

В этом случае и `__init__` будет отрабатывать от правильно класса, и все методы браться от него.

Единственно, что в такой формулировке задачи вообще нет смысла делать класс BA, т.к. можно сделать вместо него просто функцию, которая в зависимости от условия создавать либо A(), либо B().

Но в чуть более сложных случаях это имеет смысл.

Comment: Не совсем помог метод, теперь не видит  атрибуты класса, только методы. Как быть? такой вызов  AB().test   дает ошибку AttributeError: 'AB' object has no attribute 'test'

Comment: @АлександрПикин, да, я забыл, что если переопределяется `__new__`, то нужно `__init__` в нём явно дёрнуть. Я поправил код в ответе, теперь должно работать.